# ¿Cómo hacer que mi template use toda la pantalla del navegador?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

estoy usando el framework Vue.js y estoy desarollando un componente calendario y un componente navbar.
El caso es que siempre que desarrollo algo en vue.js me aparece en pequeño como si hubiese un div que me obligase a trabajar en él.
De hecho si le pongo un background a este div, obtengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que ese div ocupe todo mi navegador. De tal forma que por ejemplo, el background se vea en toda la pantalla del navegador.
Mi componente App es:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar/>
  <Calendar/>
</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import Calendar from "@/components/Calendar.vue";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar.vue";
</script>
<style setup>
div{
  background:blue;
}
</style>
```

Mi componente calendario:

```
<template>
      <div id="calendar">
    <div class="calendar-header">
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center px-2">
        <button @click="prev">
          <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M15.41 7.41L14 6L8 12L14 18L15.41 16.59L11.83 13H20V11H11.83L15.41 7.41Z" fill="currentColor"/>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <button @click="next">
          <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M8.59 16.59L13.17 12L8.59 7.41L10 6L16 12L10 18L8.59 16.59Z" fill="currentColor"/>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
      <h3 class="text-xl text-center">{{currentMonthName}}, {{currentYear}}</h3>
        <div class="calendar-body grid grid-cols-7 gap-1 px-2">
      <div v-for="day in daysWeek" :key="day" class=" font-bold">{{day}}</div>
      <div v-for="day in firstDay" :key="day" class=" font-bold">{{}}</div>
      <div :class="todayDate(date)" class="w-60" v-for="(date,idx) in lastDateOfMonth" v-bind:key="idx">{{date}}
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

¿Existe alguna forma de resetar los valores o algo del template?

Answer (score 0):

Por que no le das el background directamente al body, desde el archivo principal de styles.css. Aunque he ledio que por temas de accesibilidad no es recomendable cambiar el background total de una pagina.

Sin embargo tambien puedes darle una altura al div.

```
<style setup>
div{
  background:blue;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionarme, no ocupa el navegador entero...

Comment: Además la medida no es responsive..